# How to handle duplicate values in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

First I'm a d3.js noob :)

How you can see from the title I've got a problem with duplicated data and aggregate the values is no option, because the name represent different bus stops. In this example maybe the stops are on the fron side and the back side of a building.

And of course I like to show the names on the x-axis.

If i created an example and the result is a bloody mess, see [jsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/vy8vjy4r/).

- x = index
- name = bus stop name
- n = value

I've got a json e.g.:

```
[{
  "x": 0,
  "name": "Corniche St / Abu Dhabi Police GHQ",
  "n": 113
},
{
  "x": 1,
  "name": "Corniche St / Nation Towers",
  "n": 116
},
{
  "x": 2,
  "name": "Zayed 1st St / Al Khalidiya Public Garden",
  "n": 146
}, 
...
{
  "x": 49,
  "name": "Hamdan St / Tariq Bin Zeyad Mosque",
  "n": 55
}]
```

The problem: It is possible that the name could appear more then once e.g.

```
{
"x": 1,
"name": "Corniche St / Nation Towers",
"n": 116
}
and
{
"x": 4,
"name": "Corniche St / Nation Towers",
"n": 105
}
```

I like to know is there a way to tell d3.js not to "delete" duplicated names and instead just show all names in sequence with their values.

Any ideas or suggestions are very welcome :) If you need more information let me know.

Thanks in advanced 
Mario

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The names aren't distinct to start with, are they?

Comment: Right. It is possible that the same name appears more then once. Look at the jsFiddle. There you can see what i mean. The line is "jumping" back to the 1st appearance of the name and this behavior is not wanted.

Comment: I can see the lines jumping back, but there don't seem to be any duplicate labels on the x axis.

Comment: Indeed, that's my problem, i need those duplicate labels to draw a nice line. If you take a closer look into the json x=1 and x=4. This name should be on the labels, at least twice. This is my question is it possible to turn off the algorithm that deletes duplicate items and just print the sequence as it is regardless of whether a duplicate name appears or not. I don't want to add an idx to the stop name

Comment: You're using an ordinal scale, which has exactly this property. You either need to use a different scale, or make the names distinct (e.g. by appending an index or something like that).

Comment: Thank you Lars and Angus for this clarification.

Comment: PS In your original JSFiddle, you defined xAxisGroup twice at the bottom. One should have been yAxisGroup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lars is right: the d3.ordinal scale is doing exactly what it should: treating duplicate values as repeat instances. See here for more details: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales

You can use a regular linear scale instead, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vy8vjy4r/2/

The changes are to make the scale linear and set the domain to be the length of your dataset.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,j_data.length]).range([0, width]),
```

When you pass a value to the scale, you simply pass the position in the list. I'm using the index - the i in function(d,i) - but you could have used the x in your dataset. (I didn't use it as it looks like you don't need it.)

```
.x(function (d,i) { return x(i); })
```

Hopefully this works for you.

**Additional information on axis**

Strictly speaking, I guess this should have been an additional question, but to get the text on the axis, you can simply add these two lines of code in where you modify the text in xAxisGroup, after .selectAll("text"):

```
.data(j_data.filter(function(d,i) { return !(i%5); }))
.text(function(d){ return d.name; })
```

The axis is displaying numbers every fifth item, so we choose every fifth item from the dataset.  This gives us data that matches the existing labels, and we change the text to the .name value, see http://jsfiddle.net/vy8vjy4r/4/

This approach isn't particularly strong: it depends on D3 displaying every fifth stop, and for short or very long routes (or whatever these are) it might display all stops, or every tenth, etc. I would rather not use the D3 axis and build your own. For something like this, it shouldn't be too hard, although fitting all the names in might be hard in this space.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vy8vjy4r/5/

Comment: Ok looks fine, but i want to display the names :). So i either use ordinal and add an index to the names and after drawing the chart i remove those numbers or I use linear and replace the number after drawing with the names. I thought it would be possible without replacing the numbers. Thank you angus.

Comment: Tank you very much angus. I will play a bit with the idea of "my own" x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Try this filter,

```
var names = [];
var result = [];
var indx=-1;
for(var i=0; i< j_data.length; i++){
    indx = names.indexOf(j_data[i].name);
    if(indx==-1){
        names.push(j_data[i].name);
        result.push(j_data[i]);

    }
}
j_data= result;
```

Do this after your j_data array, it'll remove the duplicated objects from your j_data array. And see this http://jsfiddle.net/vy8vjy4r/1/

If it is not, what you are looking for, ask what change you need.

Comment: Hi, delete is no option too. I need those "duplicated" entries, because they represent a valid bus stop